# How to fix a touch point with camera fit viewport accurately?

Tags: libgdx, viewport

**`FitViewport`**

when using this viewport and get the touch point, as you can see in the below 1st GIF that the bullet is direction is not accurate to the touch point.

[image: fit viewport]

**`StretchViewport`**

but using this viewport, the touch point and bullet direction is entirely fixed and accurate.

[image: stretch viewport]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a `Camera` has a `Viewport`, use the viewport class method `unproject()` instead of using the camera class.

Answer (score 1):

You need translate screen coordinates to world space.
This code will work for you if you apply to touch position.

```
 Vector3 unproject(Vector3 screenCoords,
                     float viewportX,
                     float viewportY,
                     float viewportWidth,
                     float viewportHeight);
```

You can use it like that

```
Vector3 touch=camera.unproject( new Vector3( Gdx.input.getX(), Gdx.input.getY() , 0 ) ,viewportX, viewportY, viewportWidth, viewportHeight);
    touch.x // translated touch x
    touch.y // translated touch y
```

Or you can use also viewport.unproject() for viewports its exactly same with a first one.